# Volumes search in google book API returns different result count for the same query

Tags: javascript, html, google-books

According to the google book API documentation, the **startIndex** can be specified in URL for the start index of the collection(volumes). However, every time I perform the same query with different **startIndex**, the **totalItems** from the returned object defers. Not only that, there are always as many as 40 results in the returned object even though the **startIndex** has already exceeded *Math.ceil(data.totalItems / 40(**RESULTS_PER_PAGE**)*. Is there anything I am missing for volumes search?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=love+intitle:love&startIndex=0&maxResults=40
```

Comment: `totalItems` appears to correlate to the total number of `startIndex`es (pagination results). As far as why the `totalItems` changes when requesting a different `startIndex`: that I cannot answer: you'd have to ask a knowledgeable Google engineer why the value changes (it shouldn't). In my testing, the value becomes more accurate as you approach the final `startIndex`.

Comment: [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603938/django-google-books-api-totalitems-is-changing) it seems related to your question.

Comment: Ok I figured it out already. Thanks